# How to pass a variable from views to base.html in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I want to show the user's first name on the navbar of my project. This navbar is on the `base.html` file.

In my `views.py` I have created a variable that does this

```
def base(request):
    user = request.user
    u = User.objects.get(username=user)
    us = u.clients.first_name
    context = {'u': u, 'us': us}
    return render(request, "backend/base.html", context)
```

I can get it to work on any other .html file, but not on the base.html, that looks like this

```
<span class="mb-0 text-sm  font-weight-bold">{{us}}</span>
```

This is my model

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Primeiro Nome")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Apelido")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Morada")
    nif = models.CharField(max_length=9, verbose_name="NIF", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], primary_key=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=9, verbose_name="Telemóvel", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name="Email")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Clientes"
```

Comment: What is the error message or does it just not render anything?

Comment: @KentShikama It doesn't render anything. If I use `{{user}}` it will render the username, but if I use `{{us}}` (after the variable defined on the views.py) it renders nothing.

Comment: What is the django version?

Comment: @felipsmartins 3.0.3

Comment: Are you sure you have related Client object ( with same user)  for user you are trying to list in database

Comment: @iklinac Yes, when I pass the variable to any other page, e.g. `homepage.html`, it works. The first name is rendered.

Comment: WOW that's pretty weird! But hard to debug it without any environment on this side

Comment: I just can figure it out you're using another `backend/base.html`

Comment: @felipsmartins because I have 2 apps in django `backend` (dashboard) and `frontend` (website).

Comment: @felipsmartins just solved it, see my answer.

Comment: still weird since varibles should be in the extended and base template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

I was able to solve this by creating a `context_processor.py` with the following code

```
from .models import Clients, Hotels, Trip, Flight
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def add_variable_to_context(request):  
    user = request.user
    u = User.objects.get(username=user)
    us = u.clients.first_name
    uv = u.clients.avatar
    return {
        'u': u,
        'us': us,
        'uv': uv
    }
```

Comment: Was typing my answer but there you go, also don't forget to add ```'appname.context_processors.add_variable_to_context',``` in Templates (context_processors)

Comment: Great! Might as well mark your own answer as the answer to your question so this question will be closed

Comment: @Steven I tried, but it will only let me do it in 2 days.

Comment: Well no worries, as long as you've solved your question haha

Answer (score 0):

> In *views.py* try to use *render_to_string* function.  And dont forget to configure the static files settings in configuration file.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

context = {'u': u, 'us': us}
render_to_string('html_name.html', context)
```